# How to add extensions using cdn in cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I want to use the klay extension for layout in cytoscape.
I got the cdn for it https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/cytoscape-klay.
How do I use it only with the cdn.

Answer (score 2):

Got the extension working with only cdns
I was missing one js file - https://unpkg.com/klayjs@0.4.1/klay.js

got this from this demo - https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cytoscape-klay@3.1.1/demo.html